# Scrolling в android, как сделать всё прокручиваемым а TableRow нет

Tags: android-studio, android-scrollview

Есть `TableLayout` в котором много `TableRow`, как сделать что бы самый верхний `TableRow` не прокручивался а все остальные прокручивались? 
Я пытался не вставлять `ScrollingView` в первый `TableRow`, но выдает ошибку что нужно что бы ScrollingView был родителем.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```